# Javascript - Split an array into separate <td>

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Im struggling on splitting an array into 3 separate td's.

```
$(runner).find(".third_level .jockey_stats").html(runners[i].jockey_stats);
$(runner).find(".third_level .trainer_stats").html(runners[i].trainer_stats);
```

jockey_stats & trainer_stats are both arrays which hold 3 pieces of information which render like this:

```
<td>248-28(11.3%)-35</td>
```

I would like it to display within the table like this

```
<td>248</td>
<td>28(11.3%)</td>
<td>35</td>
```

HTML

```
<table class="third_level" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><%= I18n.t("views.wagering.third_level.career_earnings") %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t("views.wagering.third_level.jockey_stats") %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t("views.wagering.third_level.trainer_stats") %></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <% if @third_level_runner %>
            <td class="earnings tl_data"><%= number_to_currency(@third_level_runner.total_earnings, :unit => "₪", :precision => 0, :delimiter => ",") %></td>
            <td class="jockey_stats tl_data"><%= @third_level_runner.jockey_stats %></td>
            <td class="trainer_stats tl_data"><%= @third_level_runner.trainer_stats %></td>
        <% else %>
            <td class="earnings tl_data">-</td>
            <td class="jockey_stats tl_data">-</td>
            <td class="trainer_stats tl_data">-</td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Have you tried? splitting on the dash (`-`) seems to be what you're after

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: posted an answer, that it's pretty easy, really

Comment: Did it work? was it helpful? It's a duplicate of your own question, btw... SO admins don't take too kindly to question-spamming

Comment: it's working to a point. its splitting only two of the elements and joining the <td>s inside the <td class="jockey_stats> ... not sure why its removing one of the strings

Comment: Which of the suggested options are you using, and what does your data _actually_ look like? [Perhaps a fiddle might help](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/br7nr/1/  and Im using jockey_stats.split('-').join('</td><td>'));

Comment: That's because you're setting the `innerHTML` of a tbl cell, not the outerHTML. use `replaceWith` to set outerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll bite:

```
$(runner).find(".third_level .jockey_stats").html(runners[i].jockey_stats.replace(/-/g, , '</td><td>'));
```

That should do the trick.
If you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
$(runner).find(".third_level .jockey_stats").html(runners[i].jockey_stats.split('-').join('</td><td>'));
```

The regular expression approach works like this: The expression matches a dash (`-`), and replaces it with `</td><td>`, by using the global flag (`g`), the expression is applied to all dashes in the string.
 Effectively `<td>248-28(11.3%)-35</td>` becomes `<td>248</td><td>28(11.3%)-35</td>`, then `<td>248</td><td>28(11.3%)</td><td>35</td>`

The `join-split` approach causes a bit more overhead in this case, first the string is broken up into an array of strings:

```
'<td>248-28(11.3%)-35</td>'.split('-');
```

becomes:

```
['<td>248','28(11.3%)','35</td>']
```

To which `join` is applied, with `</td><td>` as delimiter, which yields

```
<td>248</td><td>28(11.3%)</td><td>35</td>
```

If, however, the markup might contain dashes, you should go for the regex approach, and work on the expression a bit. A lazy solution could be:

```
jockey_stats.replace(/\>[^<]*/g, function(inner)
{//inner matches substring starting from first > to first <
    return inner.replace(/-/g, '</td><td>');
});
```

This way, attributes inside a tag, that contain a dash won't be treated.
The expressions are rather simple: 
`\>[^<]*` matches `>` and all subsequent chars, if any, that *aren't* `<`, in other words, everything inbetween `>` and `<`. 
This match is then passed to a function, which replaces all dashes with `</td><td>`.

For example:

```
console.log('<td data-type="foo">248-28(11.3%)-35</td>'.replace(/\>[^<]*/g, function(inner)
{
    return inner.replace(/-/g, '</td><td>');
}));
```

logs `"<td data-type="foo">248</td><td>28(11.3%)</td><td>35</td>"`